# Adding Web API controllers to a migrated Web Forms project in VS 2015

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms, asp.net-web-api2, visual-studio-2015

I just migrated an ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms project from VS 2010 to 2015. I now want to add a WebApi controller as a part of refactoring the project, but when I go to "Add New Item" -> Web -> Web API, it shows no items but says "Please choose a project type"

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: did you upgrade the targetting framework to at least 4.5?

Comment: @DanielA.White - boom, that was it! I updated the project to 4.6 and now I see the web api item. Add it as an answer and I'll mark it as such. Your response deserves extra points :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the project to target at least .NET 4.5 to support Web API.